# bash create array of ids for launching processes

Tags: bash

I have to come up with an array of values. They're going to represent the server and/or virtual server ids they'll represent. So I have to run 100 application instances on 25 servers. 

`server 1 runs process 1,26,51,76
server 2 runs process 2,27,52,77
...
server 25 runs process 25,50,75,100`

I need a way to execute the scripts like this

```
# hostname is in a format like production-01.localdomain
host_id=`hostname | tr 'A-Za-z-.' ' ' | tr -d '[[:space:]]'`

# need to create array of server ids in server_ids

for server_id in server_ids
do
    /usr/local/bin/virtual_process $server_id
done
```

but I don't know how to create the server_ids array. Help!

Comment: Does this help? http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/

Comment: There's no `foreach` command in `bash`, it's just `for`.

Comment: you're right. I mixed languages for a second I meant for

Comment: The `tr`/`awk` pipe will always print "1".

Comment: Thanks, I tried it on server 01 and didn't think to try server 02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here ya go. This solves your problem by creating a space separated string instead of an array which would be overkill

```
# hostname is in a format like production-01.localdomain
server_id=`hostname | tr 'A-Za-z-.' ' ' | tr -d '[[:space:]]' | awk '{print NR}'`

# need to create array of server ids in server_ids
server_ids="$server_id $(( $server_id+25 )) $(( $server_id+50 )) $(( $server_id+75 ))"

for server_id in $server_ids
do
    /usr/local/bin/virtual_process $server_id
done
```

Comment: Also, the `host_id` value I guess would need to be the initial `server_id`? Otherwise it will always start from a base of 0.

Comment: ya, that was a typo. should have been server_id

Comment: While it's understandable that your answer focuses on the  crux of the question, it may be confusing to future readers to copy the _broken_ parts of the OP's code verbatim (the command substitution to extract the number from the hostname, the pseudo `for` loop code).
Also, while composing a single argument string to pass unquoted to `for` happens to work in this case, it's a fragile technique in general. I suggest adding either a comment to that effect to the question, or modify the solution to use an _array_ variable instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idiomatic Bash solution that should work as-is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Extract the base server ID by extracting the number from the hostname,
# eliminating any leading zeros.
# E.g., 'production-01.localdomain' -> '1'
baseServerId=$(( 10#$(tr -dC '[0-9]' <<<"$HOSTNAME") ))

# Loop 4 times, starting with the base server ID and
# adding 25 in each subsequent iteration.
for (( i = 0; i < 4; ++i )); do
  /usr/local/bin/virtual_process "$(( baseServerId + i * 25 ))"
done
```

As you can see,

- A single `tr` command utilizing `-C` for the *complement* is enough to extract digits only: `-dC '[0-9]'` means: delete (`-d`) everything *but* (`-C`) digits (`[0-9]`).

  - Since the resulting number can have leading zeros, these must be removed to avoid misinterpretation as an *octal* number. Evaluating the `tr` command inside an arithmetic expansion `$(( ... ))` with `10#` - the desired number base - prepended to the output from `tr`, does just that.
- No need for an *array* of server IDs when an arithmetic, C-style loop will do.

---

That said, since the list of offsets is so small and has fixed increments, a more succinct solution is:

```
for offset in 0 25 50 75; do
  /usr/local/bin/virtual_process "$(( baseServerId + offset ))"
done
```

A more algorithmic approach using [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) (which, it should be noted, only supports *literal* arguments; Bash v4+ is required due to using a 3rd argument to specify a *step* value):

```
for offset in {0..75..25}; do
  /usr/local/bin/virtual_process "$(( baseServerId + offset ))"
done
```

Comment: When I tried this I got an error, "08: value too great for base (error token is "08")" is there a way to get the int value for the string "08"?

Comment: @Johnny3653925: My bad - I hadn't thought of leading zeros, which causes misinterpretation as an _octal_ number; please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a sequence of numbers from 1 to 25 you can use bash's [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).

```
for server_id in {1..25}
do
    /usr/loca/bin/virtual_process $server_id
done
```

Comment: I need to have current server id + 0, current server id + 25,current server id + 50 and current server id + 75,